# How do I do batch updates?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I do batch updates in CodeIgniter instead of firing query each and every time in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's active record class has an insert_batch() method that does just this and takes care of escaping the data.

```
$data = array(
  array('name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@email.com'),
  array('name' => 'Sue', 'email' => 'sue@email.com')
);

$this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: but this will **INSERT** new data as a batch in the table 'my_table' . How do we define the **WHERE** clause for batch updating specific rows containing specific email addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql can do multiple updates or inserts. Usually in an Active Record pattern you do inserts one by one, but for bulk updates or inserts you can do this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1),Col2=VALUES(Col2);";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: To add to your comment, you can also use query bindings with that. That way CI will autoescape the values for you. ie. "INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?)"  $this->db->query($sql,array(1,1,1,2,2,3));

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of other old-fashioned Code Igniter users (like myself):

> You’re using an old version? insert_batch and update_batch have been around for over a year *[Sep/2010]*. If you’re not going to upgrade you would have to run an insert query for each row, or manually construct a batch insert statement.

From: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/188416/#891199

Answer (score 0):

This question was about updates, but the accepted answer is for inserts.

Here is how you do a batch update:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

This example is from the CodeIgniter user guide:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update